# Returning a value from a .then() in a promise?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, fs

I am attempting to read a file as JSON, manipulate the JSON, then return the manipulated JSON to the flatten function. Below are my promise and my flatten function.

**Promise**

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (filePath) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else fulfill(res);
    });
  });
};
```

**Flatten Function**

```
 flatten: (baseLoc, filePath, updateRev) => {
return readFilePromise(filePath)
    .then((data) => {
      const jsonObject = Object.assign({}, data);
      const flatJson = flattener(jsonObject, baseLoc);
      if (flatJson.$meta) {
        delete flatJson.$meta;
      }
      if (updateRev === true || updateRev === 'true') {
        flatJson.id = incrementVersion(flatJson.id);
      }
      return flatJson;
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}
```

I am getting a {} upon returning the promise. If I do not return the promise, and instead rely on the return flatJson statement, I get undefined. I am unsure as to why this is happening because, from all that I have seen already on StackOverflow/Google, I have everything structured correctly.

What is odd, is that if I debug through the code, I can see that the return flatJson statement does in fact hold the value I am looking for, it is just when another function invokes the flatten function, that I end up with an undefined or a {}.

Comment: no matter how much promise-foo you wrap this in, you'll never get `flatten` to return the flattened result. It will either return a promise, or accept a callback to be called later with the result.

Comment: How do you call it? Something like `flatten(…).then(JSON.stringify).then(send)`?

Comment: @Bergi I am calling it from a separate file as `app.flatten(params)` would I need to set up flatten as a promise in order to make use of the syntax you provided? I am relatively new to promises so sorry if these are noob questions

Comment: @KevinB Would I need to set `flatten` as a promise as well? How can I make use of the data I want to return? I am relatively new to promises and they are throwing me a little.

Comment: @Steve The code you posted should do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the result of an asynchronous function in a synchronous style using the await keyword inside an async context like so:

```
async function getResultDirect(req, res) {
  let result = await flatten(baseLoc, filePath, updateRev);
  return result;
}
```

But that just hides asynchronicity one level down the stack. No other way around.